# hook_node_view selectively responding

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I have inherited a complex site with multiple node type.

My current task is to prevent some nodes from loading based on some preset conditions. To accomplish that I used **hook_node_view** in the following function:

```
function accessibility_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
    drupal_set_message('Node View Responding'); 
}
```

That's just a simple test but I find that code responds on some nodes types but not on others.

Does anyone know a reason why that would be happening, please?

Comment: where does this function live? your theme template.php, custom module?

Comment: @longboardnode: The function is in a custom module

Comment: Are you sure the content type you try to hide are nodes ? Because hook_node_view fire before all node rendering.

Comment: @TytooF: Absolutely 100% sure they are nodes. They list in the content section and have the same page tabs as the nodes which respond to my code

Comment: I implemented hook_init() in my module and the message I included in that function loads on all node. Of course, hook_node_view() is the most appropriate for my purposes but it doesn't respond :-(

Comment: @sisko ok, any access modules in place (ie nodeaccess, TAC, etc)

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @longboardnode: yes, I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long and confusing time experimenting with a lot of various hooks, I finally found **hook_node_access**.

I'm not sure if I had tried it previously but it seems to do the trick.

I used the following code to test when any node of any type is being viewed at which point I test for the presence of an particular taxonomy and value to determine if I want certain roles to view and read the page:

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account){
    if($op == 'view'){
        if( isset($node->field_accessibility['und'][0]) ){
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps @longboardnode

Comment: cool. not sure if you are aware of [Taxonomy Access Control module](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) which pretty much does that... but may be too heavy for your needs.